# Is nested CoVariance becomes Contravariance?

Tags: c#, covariance, contravariance

I understood the Concepts of CoVariance and CotraVariance as, when ever an Interface  need to be marked as **Read-only** then we use **out T** and for **Write-only** interface we use **in T** so that these make sure the Type Safety over getting and setting things of an Object. But when we nest these how does ContraVariance is treated as CoVariance. For Example:

```
interface IObservable<out T>
{
    IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> o);
}
interface IObserver<in T>
{
    void OnNext(T t);

    void OnError(Exception e);

    void OnCompleted();
}
```

Please explain with an example how nested things change their variance.
or Please redirect me to a good Reading Material. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's nothing nested in that code?

Comment: Sorry, I didnt find exact word. Here IObserver is a Contravariant over T. I expected the IObservable to have <in T> since it takes IObserver<T> (Some Container of T).

Comment: @Enigmativity The contravariant `IObserver<>` is used as an "incoming" parameter in the method `Subscribe` of the other interface, and the other interface can legally be declared covariant.

Comment: For the reading material the Theory of Objects written by Martin Abadi and Luca Cardelli contains a section about this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us write `⊂` (a modified kind of less-than symbol) for the "is a" relation we have for reference types. For example `Elephant ⊂ IMammal`, or `IMammal ⊂ IAnimal`.

Look at `IObserver<>` first:

```
interface IObserver<in T>
{
    void OnNext(T t);
    // other members irrelevant
}
```

The "in" means it is contravariant. Contravariant means:

> If `X ⊂ Y`, then `IObserver<Y> ⊂ IObserver<X>`.

The contra- is because the order of `X` and `Y` changes when you "apply `IObserver<·>` on both sides of the `⊂`". That is similar to multiplying an inequality (from math) by a *negative* number on both sides. You have to swap the two sides of the inequality (or turn the `⊂` into a `⊃`).

The reason why it is allowed to have `IObserver<T>` contravariant in `T` is because `T` is only used for a value parameter in a method (namely `OnNext`).

Suppose we have an instance of `IObserver<IMammal>`. This can take in any `IMammal` in its `OnNext(IMammal t)` method. Can this instance act as an `IObserver<Elephant>` also? Yes, because if it can take in any `IMmammal`, then in particular it can take in an `Elephant`, and so the contravariance is safe and sound. Because `Elephant` "is an" `IMammal`, then `IObserver<IMammal>` "is an" `IObserver<Elephant>`.

The contravariance reverses the relation.

Now, let us look at the other type (and now we come to what you are asking!). I rename it from `IObservable<>` to `IVable<>`:

```
interface IVable<out T>
{
    IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> o);
}
```

The "out" means covariant. Covariant means:

> If `X ⊂ Y`, then `IVable<X> ⊂ IVable<Y>`.

This is like in math when you multiply both sides of an inequality by a *positive* number. `X` and `Y` are *not* swapped (co-).

But how can `IVable<T>` be covariant, when it has a method, `Subscribe`, that takes in "something with `T`"? That is because that "something" is contravariant in `T`!

Let us see if it is safe and sound. So, suppose we have an instance which is `IVable<IMammal>`. This means that it has a `Subscribe` which can take in any `IObserver<IMammal>`. But the latter is contravariant, so because an `IMammal` "is an" `IAnimal`, then any `IObserver<IAnimal>` "is an" `IObserver<IMammal>`. So this shows us that our `IVable<IMammal>` can act as an `IVable<IAnimal>` as indicated by covariance. So all is good.

In conclusion: Taking "in" something which is **contravariant** in `T`, acts like "out" in `T`. Similarly, sending "out" something which is **contravariant** in `T`, act like "in" in `T`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for valuable comments.